# Datatables.js: How to read in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, datatables

So I've been messing around with Datatables.js but I can't seem to populate it with results. So I have a Java servlet that returns the following JSON:

```
[{"fileName":"report (1).xlsx","fileSize":"82 KB","fileDate":"07/13/2016 15:19:43"},{"fileName":"report (2).xlsx","fileSize":"11 KB","fileDate":"07/07/2016 11:35:47"},{"fileName":"report (3).xlsx","fileSize":"11 KB","fileDate":"07/07/2016 11:35:47"},{"fileName":"report (4).xlsx","fileSize":"9 KB","fileDate":"07/13/2016 15:20:54"}]
```

My HTML looks likes:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Date</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

My JS looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
        "url": "/TR3Application/FileViewerServlet",
        "dataSrc": "",
        "type": "GET"
        }
        } );


});
```

When I just call AJAX and log what it returns, I'm getting the exact same JSON response from the servlet. But the Datatables don't seem to populate anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need a <tbody> tag in the HTML for dataTables to populate. Just add an empty one.

Comment: Do you need `columns: [ { data: 'fileName' }, { data: 'fileSize' }, { data: 'fileDate' }]`?

Comment: Also, shouldn't that be `$('#example').DataTable(...)` (capital D)?

Comment: @smarx Actually, both `DataTable` and `dataTable` are acceptable. They have slightly different use cases, based on whether you want jQuery API or DataTables API. See [this forum post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/64175/#Comment_64175)

Comment: I have tried all of the solutions, but I can't seem to get it to work. One thing that I saw was that in the XHR view, I don't see any calls to the servlet at all. I'm following the exact documentation and I don't know whats going on.

Comment: @user2827224 can you update your code in the answer to what you have now, after trying the suggestions? That might help us to narrow down your issue further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let dataTables knows the columns - Json mapping.

```
    <tr>
        <th data-data="fileName">Name</th>
        <th data-data="fileSize">Size</th>
        <th data-data="fileDate">Date</th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: A better way to let datatables know the columns is what @smarx mentioned in his comment on the question, with the `columns` option.